# Jeet and :last-child pseudo

Tags: css, stylus

When using `j-column`, Jeet adds

```
margin-right: 0;
```

to every element via the `:last-child` pseudo class. 
So if I have

```
section.main
  j-column(7/10)
aside
  j-column(3/10)
```

I get a css like this:

```
section.main {
  ...
  margin-right: 3%;
}
section.main:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
aside {
  ...
  margin-right: 3%;
}
aside:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

The question is, why the browser ignores the `section.main:last-child` property, since `section` is the last-child of its kind?
Thanks

Comment: "since section is the last-child of its kind?" - did you try using the `last-of-type` pseudo class?  - `section.main:last-of-type {}`

Comment: can you show your html?

Comment: Oh got it, so `last-child` refers to the *latest element of its container*, whatever it is. I always saw it attached to `li` elements...